# Counting the Frequency of the input on Basys2

Tags: verilog, hdl

I have written this code to get the frequency of the input on seven segment display. This is only at early stages that is why I have used only one digit for the display. I am taking input through signal generator and using Basys2 board for the output. The problem I am facing is that the frequency displayed on the board is fluctuating a lot even though I am applying constant frequency input through signal generator. Below is my code:

```
module frequencyCounter(clk, in, frequency, rst, C, AN, DP);

    input clk, in, rst;
    output reg [3:0] frequency;
    output [6:0] C; 
    output [3:0] AN;
    output       DP;

    reg [32:0] counter = 0;
    reg [3:0] cur_dig_AN;
    reg [3:0] current_digit;
    reg [6:0] segments;
    reg [3:0] frequency_reg;

    assign AN = cur_dig_AN;
    assign DP = 1;
    assign C = ~segments;

    always@(posedge clk) begin
        if(rst) begin
            frequency <= 0;
            frequency_reg <= 0;
            counter <=0;
            cur_dig_AN <=0;
            current_digit <=0;
        end
        else if (counter < 50000000) begin
            counter <= counter +1;
            if(in) 
                frequency_reg <= frequency_reg + 1;
        end     
        else begin
            counter <= 0;
            frequency_reg <= 0;
            frequency <= frequency_reg;
            if (frequency < 10) begin
                cur_dig_AN <= 4'b1110;
                current_digit <= frequency;
            end 
       end
    end

// the hex-to-7-segment decoder
    always @ (current_digit)
        case (current_digit)
        4'b0000: segments = 7'b111_1110;  // 0
        4'b0001: segments = 7'b011_0000;  // 1
        4'b0010: segments = 7'b110_1101;  // 2
        4'b0011: segments = 7'b111_1001;  // 3
        4'b0100: segments = 7'b011_0011;  // 4
        4'b0101: segments = 7'b101_1011;  // 5
        4'b0110: segments = 7'b101_1111;  // 6
        4'b0111: segments = 7'b111_0000;  // 7
        4'b1000: segments = 7'b111_1111;  // 8
        4'b1001: segments = 7'b111_0011;  // 9
        4'b1010: segments = 7'b111_0111;  // A
        4'b1011: segments = 7'b001_1111;  // b
        4'b1100: segments = 7'b000_1101;  // c
        4'b1101: segments = 7'b011_1101;  // d
        4'b1110: segments = 7'b100_1111;  // E
        4'b1111: segments = 7'b100_0111;  // F
        default: segments = 7'bxxx_xxxx;
        endcase     

endmodule
```

The way it works is that it counts number of inputs in one second. I am using 50Mhz clock (thus 50000000). Some registers like cur_dig_AN might seem redundant but as I said I was just testing at this stage. Moreover, is there any effective way of eliminating noise if it is of any concern at all in my case?

Comment: I saw the pattern of signal generator on the oscilloscope. There is some fluctuations at the crests and troughs. I am not sure if those fluctuations are that worrisome considering it seems very minute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution to my problem. The problem I was facing was that once there is an input I counted it as many times as there was clk signal and that input was there instead of just counting it once therefore I had to introduce another variable so that I don't count same input twice:

```
reg in_reg;
    if(in && ~in_reg) begin 
                    frequency_reg <= frequency_reg + 1;  //increasing freq reg for each input with in one second
                    in_reg <= 1;
                end
                else if (~in)                           //makes sure it is not counting same input twice
                    in_reg <= 0;
```

This way I am getting my correct frequency!